# How to implement PhantomJS with Selenium WebDriver using java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, screenshotexception

I'm going mad, really. I have this code:

```
public class Creazione extends TestCase {
    private PhantomJSDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        File file = new File("C:/Program Files/phantomjs-1.9.7-windows/phantomjs.exe");
        System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", file.getAbsolutePath());
        driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://www.gts.fiorentina.test/";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(baseUrl + "/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f");
        findDynamicElement(By.id("tbUserName_I"), 2000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("tbUserName_I")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("tbUserName_I")).sendKeys("rogai");
        driver.findElement(By.id("tbPassword_I")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("tbPassword_I")).sendKeys("Fiorentina2014!");
        driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin_CD")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreazione() throws Exception {
        driver.get(baseUrl + "/SegreteriaSportiva/Calciatori.aspx");
        findDynamicElement(By.cssSelector("#ASPxButton1_CD > span"), 2000);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ASPxButton1_CD > span")).click();
        findDynamicElement(By.id("FrmEdit_TS_TipoPersonaId_FK_B-1"), 2000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("FrmEdit_TS_TipoPersonaId_FK_B-1")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("FrmEdit_TS_TipoPersonaId_FK_DDD_L_LBI2T0")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("FrmEdit_Nome_I")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("FrmEdit_Nome_I")).sendKeys("Prova");
        driver.findElement(By.id("FrmEdit_Cognome_I")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("FrmEdit_Cognome_I")).sendKeys("Calciatore");
        driver.findElement(By.id("FrmEdit_TS_RuoloId_FK_B-1")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("FrmEdit_TS_RuoloId_FK_DDD_L_LBI3T0")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("FrmEdit_DataNascita_I")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("FrmEdit_DataNascita_I")).sendKeys("01/01/2014");
        driver.findElement(By.id("FrmEdit_Cittadinanza_I")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("FrmEdit_Cittadinanza_I")).sendKeys("italiana");
        driver.findElement(By.id("FrmEdit_LuogoNascita_I")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("FrmEdit_LuogoNascita_I")).sendKeys("roma");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#BTN_Edit_CD > span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("Grid_DXFREditorcol3_I")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("Grid_DXFREditorcol3_I")).sendKeys("Prova");
        assertEquals("Prova",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@id='Grid_DXDataRow0']/td[3]")).getText());
    }
}
```

After execution I get these errors during runtime, following is that trace ---

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated","request":{"headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"27","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:20497","User-Agent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.3.2 (java 1.5)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"id\":\":wdc:1402393987914\"}","url":"/clear","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"clear","directory":"/","path":"/clear","relative":"/clear","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/clear","queryKey":{},"chunks":["clear"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/e4b71580-f084-11e3-959e-273aa801dd81/element/%3Awdc%3A1402393987914/clear"}}
Command duration or timeout: 215 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.42.1', revision: '68b415a', time: '2014-05-29 16:17:18'
System info: host: 'Silvio-Acer', ip: '10.10.1.122', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_55'
Session ID: e4b71580-f084-11e3-959e-273aa801dd81
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=false, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=phantomjs, rotatable=false, driverVersion=1.1.0, locationContextEnabled=false, version=1.9.7, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=false, browserConnectionEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, proxy={proxyType=direct}, applicationCacheEnabled=false, driverName=ghostdriver, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:600)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.clear(RemoteWebElement.java:113)
    at com.example.tests.Creazione.testCreazione(Creazione.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ScreenshotException: Screen shot has been taken
Build info: version: '2.42.1', revision: '68b415a', time: '2014-05-29 16:17:18'
System info: host: 'Silvio-Acer', ip: '10.10.1.122', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_55'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:136)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated","request":{"headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"27","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:20497","User-Agent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.3.2 (java 1.5)"},"httpVersion":"1n.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"id\":\":wdc:1402393987914\"}","url":"/clear","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"clear","directory":"/","path":"/clear","relative":"/clear","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/clear","queryKey":{},"chunks":["clear"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/e4b71580-f084-11e3-959e-273aa801dd81/element/%3Awdc%3A1402393987914/clear"}}
Build info: version: '2.42.1', revision: '68b415a', time: '2014-05-29 16:17:18'
System info: host: 'Silvio-Acer', ip: '10.10.1.122', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86',       os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_55'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknow
```

I have added the phantomjs.exe to the Windows Path, added as external library the ghostdriver.jar, but nothing...

It's like two days that I'm trying to make it work...

Comment: Does it work in another browser? Is there a website or HTML that we could look at?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Try this, it worked for me**

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);                
caps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);  
caps.setCapability(
                        PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
                        "your custom path\\phantomjs.exe"
                    );
WebDriver driver = new  PhantomJSDriver(caps);
```

then rest of them are similar..and pls kindly comment your observation ,have a great day :)

Answer (score 5):

I am facing the same problem with you. I can use the same code with FirefoxDriver, but when I change it to PhantomJSDriver, it broke down.

Can you try the FirefoxDriver instead of PhantomJSDriver? Just change `driver = new FirefoxDriver()`

Actually if I modify the example code provided by selenium, change the firefox drive to phantonjs driver, it works fine. No idea what is the problem using phantomjs.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Selenium2Example  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.
        System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/phantomjs");
        WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        // Alternatively the same thing can be done like this
        // driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        element.submit();

        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        // Google's search is rendered dynamically with JavaScript.
        // Wait for the page to load, timeout after 10 seconds
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("cheese!");
            }
        });

        // Should see: "cheese! - Google Search"
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        //Close the browser
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I face same problem when i was using phantomjs 1.9.7 version. I think, this following version have some issue. Please used phantomjs 1.9.0 version. This is more stable version.

Here is the download  link:https://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/downloads/detail?name=phantomjs-1.9.0-windows.zip&can=4&q=

Answer (score 0):

Download the most recent selenium java bindings - 2.45. Then remove the 2.44 (or whatever you're using) from your library.

Then include the following in your code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService;

public void setUp() throws Exception {

DesiredCapabilities DesireCaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
DesireCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "C://phantomjs.exe");
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(DesireCaps);
```

NOTE* The location of the .exe may not be in your C drive, so you point it to exactly you've store phantom

You should be good to go after this.

Comment: It looks like you have some code missing. Formatting will help to show this.