# Process opening by application in background

Tags: c#, wpf, selenium

I would like to ask you: Is there any way to run the process which is opening during one of my application methods start?
I 'm writing an app in wpf and this is my firefox driver (selenium) which I want to run in the background:

```
//create driver using existing profile
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprof);
//change a position (browser is invisible on the screen but after 1-2 sec since ff opened so 
//this is not a solution :(. And it exist on taskbar.
driver.Manage().Window.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(-2000,0);
//change webdriver url
driver.Url = url;
//Save this ff proces to variable
Process ffProcess = HelpMethods.GetFirefoxProcess();
```

And another question when firefox will run as a background process, could I work with it normally (ex. change url or doing something on a website)?

Comment: what do you mean by "run in background"? Hidden browser window?

Comment: yes hidden window when process start

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hide firefox application in windows.
But you can use PhantomJS web-browser. This is headless browser and you will get exactly what you need.

Example:
[How to implement PhantomJS with Selenium WebDriver using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24138398/how-to-implement-phantomjs-with-selenium-in-java)

As you using, C# you need to add selenium phantomjs nuGet package to your project.
If you will use this code in console/forms application(but not in tests), also you will need to do the following to hide phantomjs console window:

[How can I start PhantomJS + Selenium window in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133336/how-can-i-start-phantomjs-selenium-window-in-background/30965714#30965714)

Comment: could you tell me how can i do this ?

Comment: but i want to use in webdriver firefox profile which i already created (i need some firefox add-ons in startup profile). Can i done it?

Comment: No, you cant. Firefox have no ability to hide UI.Chrome also.

Comment: :( mayby you know how could i start FirefoxDriver in position which i wrote in my code (no after a moment since it start)