# Execute WebDriver based tests without browser focus

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver, focus

There is a test written in `Java`, which I execute from `IntelliJ IDEA` and opens a `Firefox`. It uses some files from local machine to upload those and then receive too some files.
In this case browser window needs permanent focus, otherwise it is not working, can't select the necessary files. I would like to use machine during test is running, because test is long-running.
How could I execute it without browser focus?

Comment: Consider using the Headless browsers HtmlUnit, PhantomJS or Headless Chrome

Comment: I use Java/Selenium tests all the time and they don't need focus. I'm not sure why yours would.

Comment: @Jeffc : It needs focus, otherwise it will not put the link to the file chooser window.

Comment: It sounds like you aren't doing it correctly. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16908970/2386774

Comment: @JeffC : Type is : <input type="text" id="file-path">, so this example doesn't fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to achieve.

Try to use non GUI browsers like **PhantomJS** or **HtmlUnit**

http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/ and 
[How to implement PhantomJS with Selenium WebDriver using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24138398/how-to-implement-phantomjs-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **HtmlUnitDriver** or **PhantomJS** to Execute WebDriver based tests without browser focus.

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: What else should I change on project, to be executed in these browsers?

Comment: I think you don't have to change anything

Comment: It is not compatible with `WebDriverWait`.